# PineScript v5/ How to use a "fixed" lowest N bars back as stop loss when a order is placed?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, trading

my example

[image: 1]

I want to get the lowest price of the previous 5 bars when a long order is placed and set it as a stop-loss price. But when i try to do it in pinescript, i found that the stop-loss price will change as new bar pops up time after time, and the program will set the stop-loss price counting from "CURRENT BAR" instead of the entry order. Can anyone help me with my code, please? many thanks :')

```
strategy("Strategy Alert", overlay=true, calc_on_every_tick=true, calc_on_order_fills=true, pyramiding = 0)

//Condition 1 
BBAlert = ta.barssince(ta.crossunder(low[1], lower[1])) <= 10 and close 
> lower and close > low[1]
//Condition 2 
RSIAlert = ta.barssince(ta.crossunder(rsi,30)) <= 10 and rsi > rsi[1]
//Condition 3 (ADX>-DI>+DI)
DMIAlert = adx[1] > minus[1] and minus[1] > plus[1] and adx[1] > adx and 
minus[1] > minus and plus[1] < plus and plus < adx
//Condition Sum 
Long = (BBAlert or RSIAlert) and DMIAlert

//Define
entryp = strategy.opentrades.entry_price(strategy.opentrades - 1)
conl = entryp <= basis
varip float stoplosspricel = na
l1 = ta.lowest(low, 2)
l5 = ta.lowest(low, 6)
low1 = ta.valuewhen(strategy.position_size >= 0, l1, 0)
low5 = ta.valuewhen(strategy.position_size >= 0, l5, 0)

//Set Entry (Long)
if Long
    strategy.entry("long", strategy.long, 1, comment = "buy long")
    if strategy.position_size >= 0
        stoplosspricel := con1 ? low5 : low1
    strategy.exit("stop loss long", "long", stop = stoplosspricel)
```

hope someone can help me solve my problem and tell me how can i write the code correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Your strategy.exit is updated on each bar once your Long is on.
That's why your stop loss is updated on each bar.
You should prevent the update this way :

```
if Long and strategy.position_size == 0
    strategy.entry("long", strategy.long, 1, comment = "buy long")
    stoplosspricel := con1 ? low5 : low1
    strategy.exit("stop loss long", "long", stop = stoplosspricel)
```

Comment: sorry i am a novice pinescript coder, may I know what is the difference?

Comment: with your code, after you go Long , you adjust your strategy.exit on each bar (and so adjust your stop loss value on each bar). With my answer, once you go Long, you place an entey order and an exit order and the bars after, you don’t enter your if block because your position size is not null : then your stop loss is not updated. Please accept the answer if it helped you

Comment: the code didn't work but maybe I am missing some important information. because "Long" and "strategy.position_size == 0" can't happen together, "Long" are sets of conditions that when all of them are met, the program will place an order, so i think when "Long" are fulfilled, strategy.position_size == 0 can't be true. I updated my "Long" code for your reference.

Comment: @Toby When you don't have any position (strategy.position=0) you can have Long and then , the 'if' block is executed. After the execution of the if block, you will have strategy.position != 0 ans so your strategy.exit will not update